# TYPO3: How to check if a record is new or just a copy

Tags: copy, typo3, hook

I implemented two hooks **(processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations and processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray)** to manipulate any record after saving.

My Question is:
Every time I copy or create a record I enter the hooks and get a parameter "status" which is always "new" no matter if the record is actually new or just a copy of an existing record. 
It seems like TYPO3 handles copies as new records.

How can I check if a record is actually a copy or a new record? 
I am currently working with **`TYPO3 Version 8.7.9`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **t3_origuid**.

It should be added to your extbase domain model.

[See here.](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8.7/Ctrl/)

After handling the "copy" command the id of the original record will be copied into this field.

So in the hooks:
**processDatamap_preProcessFieldArray** or **processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray** you can access to it.

Like:

```
if(isset($fieldArray['t3_origuid']) {
   <your_code>
}
```